# Вставка текста из запомненного браузером оставляет input серым

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, input, html-form

Вставка текста из запомненного  браузером оставляет input серым
Есть поле input выводит список предложенного ранее введенного (что браузер запомнил) но после ввода из предложенного поле не меняет цвет а остается серым. Как это можно исправить? Даже чистый инпут без классов также себя ведет.

Поле со списком предложений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Остается таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя должно быть таким

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что поле читает что получил ввод (стало зеленым) но перекрывает серый фон

Я как бы нашел решение переписать стили наверно

```
user agent stylesheet
input:-internal-autofill-selected
```

Но мне интересно есть более элегантные решения )

К тамуже это не особо подходит галочка куда то пропадает или я не до конца разобрался (

Это обычный bootstrap is-valid сейчас попробовал сменить стили галочки нету (

Comment: Наверное, вы имеете в виду Chrome браузер?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko да вроде везде фпирефокс не могу проверить только а так все браузеры на хороме же сейчас все равно опера яндекс и дт

Comment: У вас запятые посыпались :( А по теме - можно решить только переписыванием стилей, как вы и сделали.